# Change line in textfile using perl

Tags: perl

I read other places on how to do this but they were confusing for me.

I want to read lines from a text file and when I come across a certain line I want to append something to it.

My code is:

```
 open my $p, "$username_filename" or die "can not open $username_filename: $!";

 foreach $line (<$p>){
     if ($line =~ /^listen/){
         `echo "whatever" >> $username_file`;
     }
 }
```

However when I run this I get this error

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' sh: -c: line 0: `echo "current_user" >> '
```

Is this way correct to edit the file and why am I getting this error?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you're using shell inside Perl, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Do you want to append to the *line* or to the *file*?

Comment: @Schwern I want to append to the line

Comment: @gettingthere Oh, that's a little harder. Let me modify my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your attempt.  The big one is that using `echo >> file` will append to the file, not insert at some arbitrary place inside the file.

Another problem is that you're trying to append to a file called `$username_file`, and you haven't declared or defined that variable.

I don't think perl lets you insert into the middle of a file.  I think your best bet would be to read the file a line at a time, and on the correct line(s), append the text you want.  Write each line to a new file, then swap the files around at the end.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $in_filename = "in.txt";
my $out_filename = "out.txt";

open (my $in, "<", $in_filename) or die;
open (my $out, ">", $out_filename) or die;

while (my $lline = <$in>)
{
    chomp $lline;
    if ( $lline =~ /listen/ )
    {
        print "$lline whatever\n";
    }
    else
    {
       print "$lline\n";
    }
 } 

close $in;
close $out;

rename $in_filename, "$in_filename.original";
rename $out_filename, $in_filename;
```

I use `chomp` to remove line endings, because `<$in>` gives us a line including its line endings, wish otherwise messes up the append.

As always there are many ways to achieve this.  I think using `sed` is probably a better option for this, but you specifically asked how to do it in perl, so perl it is.

Comment: I think you need `rename $out_filename, $in_filename` at the end there. Also you're forgetting to check if your `open`s worked.

Comment: Indeed.  Incomplete example for explanation only :-)

Comment: Without the `rename` this doesn't answer the question. And checking file operations is not something I'd leave off an answer. This is obviously a new programmer and forgetting to check if `open` worked is a classic mistake.

Comment: @Mark what is "$out_filename"? I have a file im reading from and I want to edit that file, where does $out_filename come from?

Comment: @gettingthere You can't insert into the middle of a file, as far as I'm aware.  My suggestion is that you read from the input file and write to a new file, then swap them around at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Working with files is not like editing in a word processor. Lines are an illusion, a file is just a big string of characters. You can't change a line in the middle of a file for the same reason you can't change a line in the middle of a book, the words can't be moved around to make room.

Instead, like a book, if you want to change something you need to rewrite the whole thing.

The basic algorithm is to...

1. Open the file for reading.
2. Open a temporary file for writing.
3. Read a line, alter the line, write the line.
4. Repeat 3 until done reading.
5. Overwrite the file with the temp file.

Some other notes...

[`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) writes to STDOUT by default, but you can give it a filehandle to write to instead.

`foreach my $line (<$fh>)` is unfortunately not optimized to read files. It will read the possibly enormous file into memory. `while(my $line = <$fh>)` reads one line at a time.

I've turned on [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html). This forces you to declare your variables. It protects you from typos like the one you made of `$username_file` vs `$username_filename`.

You could use something like `"$filename.tmp"` but [File::Temp](http://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp) provides temp files that are guaranteed to be temporary, unique and cleaned up when the program exits.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;     # because writing 'or die' gets old fast
use File::Temp;  # provides safe temp files    

my $filename = ...; # set it somehow

open my $read, "<", $filename;
my $temp = File::Temp->new;

while(my $line = <$read>) {
    if( $line =~ /^listen/ ) {
        chomp $line;             # remove the newline
        $line .= " whatever\n";  # add our content and put a newline back
    }

    # Write the line to the temp file
    print $temp $line;
}

# Overwrite our file with the rewritten temp file
rename $temp->filename, $filename;
```

That's inside a program.  If you just want to do it quickly, you can do it on the command line with `-i` and `-p`.

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'if( /^listen/ ) { chomp; $_ .= "whatever" }' filename
```

`-p` says to run the code on each line of the file. The line will be put into `$_` and whatever is in `$_` will be printed. `-i` says to edit the file in place. `-i.bak` makes a backup of the original file just in case you make a mistake.